# Cómo generar una imagen a partir de un componente de React JS manteniendo siempre una misma relación de aspecto

Tags: reactjs, html2canvas

a modo de entrenamiento estoy creando una web cuyo funcionamiento consiste en recibir el enlace de un tweet y llevar el contenido a un componente de React JS para luego guardarlo como imagen.

Actualmente, estoy intentando generar una imagen a partir de un componente de React JS, me encuentro usando html2canvas, pero tengo el problema de que la imagen pierde la relación de aspecto al cambiar el ancho de la pantalla.

Este es el resultado esperado en todos los escenarios al cambiar el ancho de la pantalla:
[image: Resultado esperado]

Este es uno de los resultados que ocurre al cambiar el ancho de la pantalla:
[image: resultado al cambiar el ancho de la pantalla]

El componente a guardar se encuentra en la clase: `main-container-tweet`

Esta es la manera que uso html2canvas:

```
const element = document.querySelector('.main-container-tweet');
    html2canvas(element).then((canvas) =>{
      let enlace = document.createElement('a')
      enlace.download = 'Captura.png'
      enlace.href = canvas.toDataURL();
      enlace.click();
    })
```

¿Cómo podría generar una imagen a partir de dicho componente, manteniendo siempre la misma relación de aspecto independientemente del ancho de la pantalla?
Ya sea usando html2canvas o cualquier otro método. Muchas gracias de antemano.